# How to loop through list items in material ui pagination using react

Tags: reactjs, pagination, material-ui

I want to loop through list data and render pagination... 
And also how to limit the items per page in material-ui-pagination.

Comment: Can you post code snippet?

Comment: I have a list of 30items and need to loop through these on pageChange... what prop do I need to use or how to map.  
<Pagination count={items.length} onChange={this.handleChange}/>

Comment: Check this thread: https://material-ui.com/components/pagination/" ) ...hope this helps in someway.

Answer (score 2):

I also faced issues with implementing pagination when I started with material-ui. You can actually use the material-ui's [pagination](https://material-ui.com/components/pagination/#pagination) component for the functionality you have mentioned along with the [map() funtion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to loop though your list.

You can handle the list items you show on each page with something like...

```
 yourList.subarray(((pageNumber - 1)*(numberOfItemsYouWantPerPage)), ((pageNumber)*(numberOfItemsYouWantPerPage)))
```

Check out the demo I have created for more clarity: [Pagination demo.](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-g0xo5?file=/demo.js)

Comment: That demo was super helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @CosetteN :)

Answer (score 0):

Use https://material-ui.com/api/pagination/ as a reference for material-ui-pagination props.

So basically what this component does is to create a pagination system for you, it doesn't manage any data. It can change the page number state (from 1 to 2 and so on). It needs a page prop to be passed to know what to display, so it depends on you to pass this page component and you have to update it when the page number is changed.
What you can do to display just what you want is to create a Page (that receives the data) component that you update the data depending on the page it is on. You can calculate the number of pages and the number of your list data by doing some calculations.